# Desiging FSM using D flip flop

Tags: state-machines

I want implement the state diagram using D flip flop without using K-map because of the complexity of 5 variable K-map.Is there any other method by which it can be implemented.

The state diagram is shown here:

[image]

Comment: You can avoid the K map if the machine you are designing is doing something reasonable, so you can split your FSM in simpler parts and implement heuristically each part, ie the synthesis of a 32 bit floating point multiplier. But you have got two inputs one output and just three bits for the state, grab a piece of paper and use the k map. You can go up to 7 variables k maps and don't feel much pain. Five variables is just plain simple.

Comment: You can also use free software such as Logic Friday (available [here](http://sontrak.com/)) to minimize the K-map for you. I have personally used Logic Friday for 5 variable K-maps without any issues.

Comment: Why no k maps? Homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write out the truth table and put it through a logic minimization engine, like [Espresso](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer). K-maps are really useful and easy for up to 4 variables, but ultimately, I think they are an educational tool to visualize how to do what Espresso does under the covers by hand. If, however, this is homework... you're on your own :-).

Answer (score 0):

You can produce a state machine with D-FFs and a batch of logic gates. There is nothing that demands that you use a minimization process such as can be achieved through the use of a K-map. The thing that happens if you do not do a minimization process is that you use more logic gates than necessary and invariably those gates will require more inputs. More inputs and more gates leads to a bigger circuit, increased wire count and higher build cost.

Comment: "You can produce a state machine with D-FFs and a batch of logic gates." How?

Comment: @AaronFranke - "How?" Learn by reading some text books on logic design and state machine design. Or the possibility also exists to take a class on the subject at a university.